# How do I run a Windows exe on Ubuntu natively?

Tags: windows, wine

I'm making an exe file that I want to be able to have run on both Linux and Windows, but I don't want the exe to have to run in grub. I need it to be an exe as I need it to have basically the same codebase as the windows version as that is what a friend is helping to develop.

I want to know how I could create some script or something that would allow running an exe file in ubuntu without the separation of wine. This is a program to help encrypt programs and such and uses some build in windows-based programs that it runs api triggers on so I need it to be able to interact with the filesystem directly as root.

Any ideas on how I would do this? Just to recap I don't just want to be able to run a windows program in an emulator, I want to be able to run them natively with direct access to the filesystem.

Comment: look into "QT" you can code in it and then make native programs for each platform, there will be separate installs for each, but you can share the same code-base.

Comment: Everyone, look, I get it...I asked a bad question. Someone gave a good answer, though, so I'm leaving it. Enough with the downvotes, and we can just leave it behind us with the good answer for reference.

@Mateo thanks for the tip, I will most definitely try that when I next look at that project again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wine Is Not an Emulator](http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths#head-7c9ecddfaff60d8891414b68d74277244e7109eb). It is simply an implementation of the Windows system libraries for Ubuntu. There is no faster way to run a .exe on Ubuntu than Wine.

If you want to have a shared codebase, you will want to compile it on Ubuntu. Depending on the language you are using and the system calls that are being made, this will either be very easy or a lot of work.