# Will ubuntu ever be able to natively run windows applications?

Tags: windows, emulation

I want to know if there is ever going to be a possibility that windows exe files will be able to run on linux without an emulator like wine. Is there some way of creating an api library that offers both those used by windows applications as well as those used by linux ones? What is preventing this from happening or why has it not happened yet? Wine seems to be able to run them without running a full install of windows, so while there may be some proprietary bits why can't there be a way of completely integrating it?

Comment: The people who write applications for Windows and OSX actually have a financial incentive not to recompile these programs for windows - it's not that these programs cannot be recompiled and run in Linux, it's that they don't want to.

Comment: Maybe because WINE IS NOT AN EMULATOR. (Should I add bold and italics to that as well?) Also see: https://www.reactos.org/

Comment: Then what is wine?

Comment: It is objectionable because you don't seem to show basic research: Third question on the Wine FAQ: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c9e6502ad636315e905d07f7e44594757a6738e3 (I didn't cast any votes here, mostly because Rinzwind didn't mention ReactOS.)

Comment: I had googled but the only thing that showed up was wine so I ignored those results and beyond that there was nothing

Comment: @muru reactoos is running WINE and topic clearly states "without an emulator like wine"

Comment: @Rinzwind saying ReactOS is [running wine](http://www.reactos.org/wiki/WINE) is like saying Linux is running GCC's libc. ReactOS is offtopic, but mentioning it is fine according to how I read http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11725/should-an-answer-like-remove-ubuntu-and-install-insert-distro-here-be-flagged

Comment: @muru all the windows api's are from wine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a windows exe on ubuntu natively?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/511422/how-do-i-run-a-windows-exe-on-ubuntu-natively)

Comment: how is it a duplicate? I recognised that artificially adding apis were not really possible so I asked this one asking IF ubuntu would be able to and of course 5 ubuntu fanboys wanted to be completely independent in the linux ecosystem. I had recognized that even though you can completely use the linux ecosystem exclusively for any task, but the problem is not all people use linux so sometimes we need to play nice with people from windows and mac. GIMP can't open a photoshop file natively nor can gimp easily be made to do all the functions of ps

Comment: and although lo is nice and can be used pretty well sometimes ms office is just the best for that. Why can't some system based wine installation be used? it seems the current type of wine is slow because it needs to make double calls as it receives windows type requests then it needs to inject its own ui elements THEN it can finally ask ubuntu to do what the windows program is asking it to do. Why can't that be consolidated?

Comment: @sbergeron if you have a feature request, please post it on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net) against the appropriate software. Better yet, it's all open source here, you can chip in with code. Please keep your half-assed understanding of wine at home, will you?

Comment: I understand it enough to know it is an implementation of an independently developed API and not a full virtualized environment...and that it requires significant overhead to translate the api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

That would violate copyright. Even when Windows XP is considered abondoned the copyright on it and all its parts is still there as long there is Microsoft upholding that copyright.

Besides that: we would also need a 100% compatible DX driver. Guess who owns the copyright on that? Microsoft. That would mean nVidia, AMD need to get permission to create a DX capable driver for their videocard.

Besides that: why would we ever want that to happen? Ubuntu is an operating system with its own goals and direction. I myself would not want to have MS software in my system. It would defile our operating system with the same junk Windows already has.

To be more precise: the following DLL's are copyrighted to death: NTDLL (NT kernel functions), USER32 (core functionality for building simple user interfaces), KERNEL32 (memory management, input/output operations, and interrupts), GDI32 (Windows Graphics Device Interface), en ADVAPI (security and registry calls).  Without permissions to recreate these as open source versions all you get is a limped, broken clone. Recreate any of these and you can expect a cease and desist letter.

Comment: I'm not talking about changing any architecture I'm talking about just adding compatibility so stuff like ms office or paint.net or other windows only programs (even photoshop) can run on linux as although there are a lot of free linux alternatives, a lot of people use windows and use files of formats that only windows programs can really open so having co-existing ecosystems is hurt by this exclusivity and even hurting linux's expansion because of lack of cross compatibility. some people want or NEED a middle ground and getting indignant over inclusion of cross compatibility stuff

Comment: doesn't take into account people who have a ton of time and effort invested into other computer ecosystems making the change a ton harder

Comment: @sbergeron I know but that is just it: by remaking it you need to copy Microsoft's code so it works as it works on Windows and even looking at that code is a violation in itself if you do not have written consent from MS. LO/OO is a good example of that: it is made from scratch by making its own code but it is unlikely to ever be an actual MSO.  The ONLY company that could do this would be Microsoft and why would they even consider it?

Comment: I'm not talking about copying the code, I'm talking about some deeper wine integration. As is it seems that wine needs to carry out more than twice the operations because it needs to translate every request by the windows program to something that ubuntu can understand. why not take that already created database of functions from wine and create apis for them in ubuntu so it can work almost as fast?

Comment: The answer is no, because "Ubuntu is an operating system with its own goals and direction". If you want to "create apis for them in ubuntu" feel free too, but it won't become a part of it any time soon.